# TestNG Parallel execution with selenium driver factory

Tags: java, maven, selenium, parallel-processing, testng

Trying to get a driver factory set up for a framework I am building as a learning tool.  However I am struggling to get parallel execution of the test classes in testng.

I am using the surefire plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <properties>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/master.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The version of testng I am using is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the master.xml is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="testsuite.TestCase1"/>
            <class name="testsuite.TestCase2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I have simplified the driver factory for the purposes of posting here:

```
public class DriverFactory
{
    //protected WebDriver driver;

    private DriverFactory()
    {
        //Do-nothing..Do not allow to initializethis class from outside
    }
    private static DriverFactory instance = new DriverFactory();

    public static DriverFactory getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() // thread local driver object for webdriver
    {
        @Override
        protected WebDriver initialValue()
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
            return new ChromeDriver(); // can be replaced with other browser drivers
        }
    };

    public WebDriver getDriver() // call this method to get the driver object and launch the browser
    {
        return driver.get();
    }

    public void removeDriver() // Quits the driver and closes the browser
    {
        driver.get().quit();
        driver.remove();
    }
}
```

Using the following mvn command to run:

mvn clean test

I know this is going to be something stupid on my part having read almost every tutorial, blog post and document relating to this I cad find.

Any assistance even just pointing me off in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot understand what is the problem

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Sorry, I am trying to get parallel execution within selenium using surefire and testing.  However, no matter what I try the tests keep running sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it myself all the suggestions made were correct and the logic I posted was originally correct as well.

However, the test cases themselves were not.
public class TestCase1 {

```
LandingPage page = new LandingPage();


@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {

    page.navigate();

}

@Test (priority = 1, description="SS1 Verify the login section")
@Description ("Verify that user mngr116116 can logon to the system")
public void login()
{

    System.out.println("Test Case One in " + getClass().getSimpleName()
            + " with Thread Id:- " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    page.enterUser("mngr116116");
    page.enterPass("ytUhUdA");
    page.submitBtn();

}

@AfterMethod
public void validate(){

    Assert.assertEquals(LandingPage.getExpectedPageTitle(),
            page.getObservedPageTitle());

}
```

}

This was causing the issue replace it with:

```
public class TestCase1 {

    LandingPage page;


    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {
        page = new LandingPage();
        page.navigate();

    }

    @Test (priority = 1, description="SS1 Verify the login section")
    @Description ("Verify that user mngr116116 can logon to the system")
    public void login()
    {
        page = new LandingPage();
        System.out.println("Test Case One in " + getClass().getSimpleName()
                + " with Thread Id:- " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        page.enterUser("mngr116116");
        page.enterPass("ytUhUdA");
        page.submitBtn();

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void validate(){
        page = new LandingPage();
        Assert.assertEquals(LandingPage.getExpectedPageTitle(),
                page.getObservedPageTitle());

    }

}
```

And I am in business.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

TestNG allows you to run your tests in parallel, including JUnit tests. To do this, you must set the parallel parameter, and may change the threadCount parameter if the default of 5 is not sufficient. You have to set configuration parameters:

```
 <configuration>
      <parallel>methods</parallel>
      <threadCount>10</threadCount>
  </configuration>
```

For you:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>methods</parallel>
            <threadCount>10</threadCount>
            <properties>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/master.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**UPDATE**

try the following

```
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
<test name="Test 1">
    <classes>
        <class name="testsuite.TestCase1"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test 2">
    <classes>
        <class name="testsuite.TestCase2"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: the parallel parameter is included in the master.xml.  Although I also tried the above just incase that was what the issue was.  Sadly not the case.  I add the following to both of my test cases
'code'
        System.out.println("Test Case One in " + getClass().getSimpleName()
                + " with Thread Id:- " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

The output of this is
Test Case One in TestCase1 with Thread Id:- 18
Test Case one in TestCase2 with Thread Id:- 18

As you can see it is working off the same thread.